Laravel 10 download function returns a corrupted zip file
I have developed a digital asset manager using Laravel 10. When the user downloads more that one asset i create a zip file and use laravel's response()->download() function to download it. Here is the function.
`
    $assetIds = $request->input('assetIds');

    // Create a temporary zip file
    $zipFileName = time().'_assets'.'.zip';
    $zipFilePath = storage_path('app/public/images/archive/original/' . $zipFileName);

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipFilePath, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    
    foreach($assetIds as $assetId){
        $asset = Asset::find($assetId);
        if(str_starts_with($asset->type, 'image/svg')){
            $filePath = storage_path('app/public/images/archive/svg/'.$asset->filename);
        }
        elseif(str_starts_with($asset->type, 'video')){
            $filePath = storage_path('app/public/videos/original/'.$asset->filename);
        }
        else{
            $filePath = storage_path('app/public/images/archive/original/'.$asset->filename);
        }
        

        $zip->addFile($filePath, $asset->filename);
    }

    $zip->close();

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
    ];

    $response = response()->download($zipFilePath, $zipFileName, $headers);
        
    return $response;

`
The problem is that if i open the file i get the error in windows "The archive is either in unknown format or damaged".
I tried downloading the file with ftp and had no problems. I also had not problems downloading the file from the browser by hitting the url or the file.
I tried adding 'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $zipFileName . '"', in the headers and it didn't work. I also trying adding ob_clean() and it didn't work.

Have you tried opening the version downloaded via laravel in a text or hex editor, to check what it actually contains?

I see that the laravel version contains html. Interesting... So, does this mean that the headers are not passed in the function?

No, it means that your system already wrote HTML to the output buffer before this part.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Check where the markup is generated. If you need help with removing these parts, share them

Also check if your disk space is full, an error could result in html output

If i open the zip file with a text editor i get this: The GET method is not supported for route download-assets. Supported methods: POST. However i do not use GET method. I submit a dynamic form that is created with js and the method that i'm using is POST.

Hi, did you manage to solve this problem?
